# How to test a project that need keyboard input with travis-ci.org?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, continuous-integration, travis-ci

I'm trying to test in travis-ci (continuous integration platform) a simple menu algorithm that wait for user inputs to do tasks ***(CRUD)***
like:

show, add, delete, update a registry or exit.

The following is a example code:

[Python Code](https://github.com/fit087/UFRJ_Computacao_2/blob/master/1aula_agenda.py)

This is my .travis.yml file:

```
language: python
python:
  - "2.6"
  - "2.7"
  - "3.2"
  - "3.3"
  - "3.4"
  - "3.5"
  - "3.5-dev" # 3.5 development branch
  - "nightly" # currently points to 3.6-dev
# command to install dependencies
# install: "pip install -r requirements.txt"
# command to run tests
script: 
  - python 1aula_agenda.py
```

And this was the output from travis-ci.org:

```
0.00s$ source ~/virtualenv/python2.7/bin/activate
$ python --version
Python 2.7.9
$ pip --version
pip 6.0.7 from /home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
Could not locate requirements.txt. Override the install: key in your .travis.yml to install dependencies.
$ python 1aula_agenda.py
0. Visualizar
1. Inserir um contato
2. Remover um contato
3. Alterar um contato
4. Sair do programa
Escolha uma opcao: 
No output has been received in the last 10 minutes, this potentially indicates a stalled build or something wrong with the build itself.
The build has been terminated
```

How can I do that the travis test all the options ***0***, **1**, **2**, **3**, **4** and add a name and a number in the case of the options 1 and 3?

Comment: this is not how you unit test ... but I guess you could write another python program that opens your program in subprocess and writes to `process.stdin`

Comment: thank you @JoranBeasley, but how would be that? I have never used that method.

Comment: I try this `proc = subprocess.Popen('python aula_agenda.py', 
                        shell=True,
                        stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                        ) proc.stdin.write("4\n")`  but it isn't working

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's possible create a file `testing.txt` with a battery test for test the functions of the program.

`testing.txt` contains the keyboard inputs required for the program.
 For example for test your example

```
0
1
"John Smith"
"1235-5387"
0
4
```

and include the testing.txt in the .travis.yml file:

```
language: python
python:
  - "2.6"
  - "2.7"
  - "3.2"
  - "3.3"
  - "3.4"
  - "3.5"
  - "3.5-dev" # 3.5 development branch
  - "nightly" # currently points to 3.6-dev
# command to install dependencies
# install: "pip install -r requirements.txt"
# command to run tests
script: 
  - python 1aula_agenda.py < testing.txt
```

Comment: You are my saver! Thanks! :)

Comment: See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40834265/how-can-i-generate-keyboard-inputs-for-pythons-input-function) for a solution with StringIO.