# How can I generate keyboard inputs for Python's 'input' function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, testing, input, stdin

I have a console program written in Python. I would like to test several input combinations in an automatic test routine. The input is read via Pythons `input(...)` function.

- How can I emulate a keyboard or any other input stream to send single characters or strings to `input`?
- Or do I need to replace input by another function, which is connected to my test cases?

Comment: Look at [unittest.mock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html).

Comment: Why not refactor such that you can call the actual functionality directly?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Because it's an integration test and no unit test :).

Comment: I'd suggest you mention integration testing in the question - in that case, you probably *don't* want to mock anything out.

Comment: I agree with @jonrsharpe. Unless `input` can (and will) only be called once in the entire system, mocking isn't the right way to go.

Answer (score 1):

If that is just a test case and not a "real part of big system" - meaning that you just need to pass a certain input to your command line executable ones (e.g. run test) and you are using Unix, one convenient way of doing this is using [pipes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix)):

```
// read.py 
val = raw_input()
print 'nice', val
```

then via console:

```
$ echo "hat" | python read.py 
nice hat
```

on Windows syntax is [little different](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx?mfr=true) - should be something like

```
dir> python.exe read.py < file.txt
```

One other hacky-simple way to achieve same thing is to replace `sys.stdin` with a custom stream object:

```
sys.stdin = StringIO.StringIO("line 1\nline 2\nline 3")
```

One should consider using @erip 's answer if that is something bigger than a automatisation routine or testing students' home assignments against fixed set of tests, though.

Comment: This isn't a very automated way to test software.

Comment: @erip, if you need to, let's say, test students home assignments against a fixed set of predefined tests, then why not? :) OP's original intent is not so clear. I fully agree that your solution should be used in real-world production

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`unittest.mock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) to patch the output of a function (including streams).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch

# Unit under test.
def get_input():
    my_input = input("Enter some string: ")
    if my_input == "bad":
        raise Exception("You were a bad boy...")
    return my_input

class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    # Force input to return "hello" whenever it's called in the following test
    @patch("builtins.input", return_value="hello")
    def test_input_good(self, mock_input):
        self.assertEqual(get_input(), "hello")

    # Force input to return "bad" whenever it's called in the following test
    @patch("builtins.input", return_value="bad")
    def test_input_throws_exception(self, mock_input):
        with self.assertRaises(Exception) as e:
            get_input()
            self.assertEqual(e.message, "You were a bad boy...")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```